# Render Doctrine entities including recursive relations as JSON

Tags: json, rest, symfony, doctrine-orm, entity-relationship

I am building a JSON-based REST API using Symfony2.4 with Doctrine2.

EDIT : with JsonNormalizer, I can disabled some attributes, but what if I would like to set them, without recursivity ?

Basically, what I have (working) now is :

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "first task"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "second task"
        }
    ]
}
```

What I would like is :

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "first task",
            "category": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "first category"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "second task",
            "category": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "first category"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

What was my initial problem is :

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "first task",
            "category": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "first category",
                "tasks": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "name": "first task",
                        "category": {
                            "id": 1,
                            "name": "first category",
                            "tasks": [...] // infinite...
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "name": "second task",
                        "category": {
                            "id": 1,
                            "name": "first category",
                            "tasks": [...] // infinite...
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "second task",
            "category": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "first category",
                "tasks": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "name": "first task",
                        "category": {
                            "id": 1,
                            "name": "first category",
                            "tasks": [...]
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "name": "second task",
                        "category": {
                            "id": 1,
                            "name": "first category",
                            "tasks": [...]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I have a entity A with a manyToOne relation to another entity B.

**I have implemented the reverse-side, to be able to retrieve the related A entities on the B one.**

```
class Task
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="List", inversedBy="task")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="list_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $list;

    public function toArray($recursive = false)
    {
        $entityAsArray = get_object_vars($this);

        if ($recursive) {
            foreach ($entityAsArray as &$var) {
                if ((is_object($var)) && (method_exists($var, 'toArray'))) {
                    $var = $var->toArray($recursive);
                }
            }
        }

        return $entityAsArray;
    }
}

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

class List
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Task", mappedBy="list")
     */
    private $tasks;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->tasks = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```

Then I am building the different API routes and controllers,
Rendering the output as JsonResponses,
And I would like to render, for a given list, the different tasks using the route :

```
/api/v1/lists/1/tasks
```

The task action of my controller :

```
public function tasksAction($id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $list = $em->getRepository('MyRestBundle:List')->findOneActive($id);

    if (!$list) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('List undefined');
    }

    $tasks = $list->getTasks()->toArray();

    foreach ($tasks as &$task) {
        // recursively format the tasks as array
        $task = $task->toArray(true);
    }

    $serializer = $this->get('serializer');

    return $this->generateJsonResponse($serializer->normalize($tasks), 200);
}
```

But unfortunately, I always get a memory leak, because the call of toArray() is recursive, so each task has a list property which has a tasks collection etc.

PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 130968 bytes) in src/Symfony/Component/Serializer/Serializer.php on line 146

I am wondering what would be the cleanest way to render entities with relations as JSON objects with Symfony2 ?

Do I really have to loop on my tasks to execute the "toArray()" method ?

I have also tried without it, without more success, except that the leak in in the file : src/Symfony/Component/Serializer/Normalizer/GetSetMethodNormalizer.php...

I have also tried without the JMSSeralizer, and the memory leak is thrown in my own php file.

Of course, I could increase the memory limit, but as it is an infinite loop problem of toArray() calls, it will not solve my problem.

How to format it properly ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a feeling that we might be overthinking this. Would that work for you?

```
// In your controller

$repo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MyRestBundle:List');
$list = $repo->findActiveOne($id);

$tasks = $list->getTasks()->toArray();

$serializer = $this->get('serializer');
$json = $serializer->serialize($tasks, 'json');
```

Why is Task Entity recursive? A task can not include another task. Only a List can include an array of Tasks. So basically all we should do is get this array from the List entity and serialize it. Unless I am missing something.

**EDIT:**

You can ask the serializer to ignore certain attributes as mentioned by the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#ignoring-attributes-when-serializing):

```
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\JsonEncoder;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\GetSetMethodNormalizer;

$normalizer = new GetSetMethodNormalizer();
$normalizer->setIgnoredAttributes(array('age'));
$encoder = new JsonEncoder();

$serializer = new Serializer(array($normalizer), array($encoder));
$serializer->serialize($person, 'json'); // Output: {"name":"foo"}
```

Try to follow that example and just ignore the `$list` attribute in the `Task` entity.

**EDIT2:**

You don't need 'list' inside each task since it's the same. Your json should have 'list' and 'tasks' at the same level. then 'tasks' would be an array of tasks which will not contain 'list'. to achieve that you can have something like `array('list' => $list, 'tasks' => $tasks)` and serialize that.

Comment: I could add such a kind of getter in my Entity List, but why ? Should I call it anywhere ?

Comment: I changed the example above. Maybe that would be more helpful

Comment: Task entity is not recursive.
But I implemented the reverse-side of list and tasks.
So a task is part from a list, which can have some tasks. The problem is that the relations are infinite because of this reverse-side... A task a list that has tasks that have lists that have tasks etc.

I have retried your method but it is still not working, sorry.

Comment: Oh, really thanks, this is a point of the documentation I totally missed !

So, now it is working well when I remove the relations with setIgnoredAttributes(), at least.
But what if I would like them ?

Comment: What if you would like what? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: What if I would like to include the "list" property in each "task" json array of the current list, but for this list, do not include the children tasks ?

Comment: Since there is only one "list" for all the related tasks. I would say that you should serialize the list entity and ignore its tasks attribute so you won't have the problem you had earlier.

Comment: Yeah, this is what I would to do, but how ?
I have updated the question with some JSON examples, to make it easier to understand

Comment: You don't need 'list' inside each task since it's the same. Your json should have 'list' and 'tasks' at the same level. then 'tasks' would be an array of tasks which will not contain 'list'. to achieve that you can have something like `array('list' => $list, 'tasks' => $tasks)` and serialize that.

Comment: Okay, but what if the "list" entity is not the only entity that I have ?
What if I have some categories for the tasks for instance ? I would like to include these relations in the JSON response

Comment: You don't need to bidirectionally link all your Entities. Categories don't need to have tasks as a attribute. so if it didn't it can be serialized with no problem.

Comment: Indeed, you are right, I had a wrong bad feeling about it :)
Thanks a lot, I cannot consider my problem definitely solved but I have a working alternative at least !

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

If I understand what your code is doing, I think the toArray($recursive) function goes into infinite recursion both directly (whenever $var = $this) and indirectly (i.e. by a sibling iterating through its own list and calling toArray of the original task again). Try keeping track of what's been processed to prevent infinite recursion:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="List", inversedBy="task")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="list_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $list;
private $toArrayProcessed = array();

public function toArray($recursive = false)
{
    $this->toArrayProcessed[$this->getId()] = 1;

    $entityAsArray = get_object_vars($this);

    if ($recursive) {
        foreach ($entityAsArray as &$var) {
            if ((is_object($var)) && (method_exists($var, 'toArray')) && !isset($this->toArrayProcessed[$var->getId()]) {
                $var = $var->toArray($recursive);
            }
        }
    }

    return $entityAsArray;
}
```

Comment: It is exactly my problem. Unfortunately, this solution does not work because the property $tasks is of type "Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection", that implements a "toArray()" method, but does not have an ID.
It would have worked with direct entities but does not with arrays of entities !